# ココロが上手くできていると思った - meaning

Tags: meaning

> 本当に真っ白になるんですね。 また、ココロが上手くできていると思ったのは、怖い話を聞くと耳をふさぐんですね。怖いものは見たくないから、がんも見ない。

I think it means something like: "I thought that being tough meant blocking out the bad". I haven't heard ココロが上手くできている before. I think it means being mentally strong maybe?

Comment: Could you add what specifically about the sentence is unclear to you? Or your attempt at understanding it's meaning?

Comment: Hi Garbaz. I think it means something like:

Comment: Hi @Garbaz. For wider context it's a person talking about how they felt when they received a diagnosis of a serious illness.Here is the surrounding text.本当に真っ白になるんですね。
また、ココロが上手くできていると思ったのは、怖い話を聞くと耳をふさぐんですね。怖いものは見たくないから、がんも見ない。I think it means something like: "I thought that being tough meant blocking out the bad". I haven't heard ココロが上手くできている before. I think it means being mentally strong maybe?